# Select dropdown in Geckoview

Tags: kotlin, dropdown, geckoview

Im trying out GeckoView on Android studio, using Kotlin
Everything works fine, except trying to click on select dropdown menus.
I believe I have to implement the GeckoSession1.PromptDelegate, but I struggle to find some working kotlin code to use

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You have a full basic implementation of PromptDelegate in the GeckoView sample application.

https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/geckoview_example/src/main/java/org/mozilla/geckoview_example/BasicGeckoViewPrompt.java

Answer (score 0):

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58670925/5362795), though not Kotlin specific. Taking a look at mozilla-mobile code at [Android Components > Feature > Prompts](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-android/tree/main/android-components/components/feature/prompts), such as [ChoicePromptDelegate.kt](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-android/blob/9de5ab8cc098674aad5190ce8b00ae6be65e9bd0/android-components/components/browser/engine-gecko/src/main/java/mozilla/components/browser/engine/gecko/prompt/ChoicePromptDelegate.kt) may send you in the right direction.