# GeckoView implemetation

Tags: geckoview

Can someone please show some examples of geckoview usage in android app? The samples available are not useful for novice programmers, at least for me. The already available samples link is given below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691172/10331824

I tried to add geckoview to open a webapp in android app. I can do it to open the webapp but not able to select items from a dropdown list available on the app. I need help in this regard. Thanks in advance...